# Why do they return the same value even if I'm adding extra condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the gem called `acts_as_paranoid`, which enables logic deletion.

```
1. <% @codes_confirmed_count = Code.where(:deleted_at => nil, :created_at => check_date.beginning_of_day..check_date.end_of_day).count %>   

2. <% @codes_all_count = Code.where(:created_at => check_date.beginning_of_day..check_date.end_of_day).count %>
```

These codes return the same value.

2nd one should return the value larger than 1st one because there's no `:deleted_at => nil`

But indeed there are some records that are deleted(which means having the datetime value in `deleted_at` collumn)

How can I ignore acts_as_paranoid here?

Comment: 1. look into `with_exclusive_scope`, 2. write a few testcases or your solution will break with the next acts_as_paranoid update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get the count of all codes (deleted + non-deleted) by

```
<% @codes_all_count = Code.with_deleted.where(:created_at => check_date.beginning_of_day..check_date.end_of_day).count %>
```

You can refer to their [github page](https://github.com/goncalossilva/acts_as_paranoid#filtering) to look for more methods.